# How to Filter the list and then display it

Tags: reactjs

Goal:
In the beginning, the list is emphty.
When you write something in the textbox, a call should by made by using api and the data list should be filtered by the input data.
When the process is completed, the result should display.

When you make the textbox to be emphty, the list should be emphty.

Problem:
I don't know how to solve it.
What part am I missing?

Info:
I'm newbie in reactjs.

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-search-filter-fhr4pm

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
// import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      error: null,
      Loaded: false,
      albums: []
    };

    this.filterList = this.filterList.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount(){

  }

  filterList(e){

    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(albums => {

        this.setState({ Loaded: true, albums }) 

        albums = albums.filter(item => {
          return item.toLowerCase().search(
            e.target.value.toLowerCase()
            ) !== -1;
        });

        this.setState({ Loaded: true, albums }) 


      },
      error => { this.setState({ Loaded: true, error }); })
  }

  render() {
    const { albums } = this.state;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.filterList} />
        <ul>
          {albums.map(album => (<li key={album.id}>{album.title}</li>))}
        </ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was lucky to find a a solution to it.

Need to have fetch inside of seach method

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-filter-search-demo-xu2nt6

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      searchTerm: ''
    };
    this.showDetails = this.showDetails.bind(this);
    this.searchTerm = this.search.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {

  }

  search(e) {

    if(e.target.value.length !== 0)
    {
      fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`).then((res) => res.json()).then((data) => {
        this.setState({users: data})   
      })

      console.log(e.target.value)
      this.setState({searchTerm: e.target.value})
    }
    else
    {
      this.setState({users: []})
    }
  }

   showDetails(user) {
     user.show = !user.show;
     this.setState({...user});
     console.log(this.state)
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="container">
      <header>
        <h1> React Filter Search Demo</h1>
      </header>
      <input class="search-box" onKeyUp={(e) => this.searchTerm(e)}   type="text"></input>
        <ul class="collapse-able">
        {this.state.users.filter(user => {
          return user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.searchTerm) > -1;
        }).map((user) => {
          return (<li><h2>{user.name}</h2></li>);
        })}
      
        </ul>
      
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```